# How to Check a String for specific word in android studio

Tags: java, android, string, android-studio

I want to check a string for a specific word so when I find my required word in a string then I want to print another variable data to my text box, m not getting any error but also i m not getting my required output.
i  tried the code below

```
 String data = intxt.getText().toString();
        String [] dat=data.split("");

        for (int i = 0; i < dat.length; i++)
        {
                   if(dat[i].equals("Button") ||  dat[i].equals("button"))
                     outtxt.setText(btncode);
                   
        }

            }
        });
```

Comment: "myString".contains(word) doesn't work for you?

Comment: You might want to ignore case: ``"My String".toLowerCase().contains(word.toLowerCase());``

Comment: its works in case if user only type button but the scenario is if user tye"create a button" then I should pick "button" from the string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    String data = intxt.getText().toString();

      if(data.contains("Button") ||  data.contains("button")){
              outtxt.setText(btncode);
            }
```

Comment: or: data.toLowerCase().contains(word.toLowerCase());

Comment: Hey Sadegh, can you help me answer this other question that I have?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67985251/speech-to-text-failed-not-able-to-find-the-problem

Answer (score 1):

you can use **yourstring.contains("want_to_check_word")**

```
public class Sample_String {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str_Sample = "This is a String contains Example";
        //Check if String contains a sequence
        System.out.println("Contains sequence 'ing': " + str_Sample.contains("ing"));
        System.out.println("Contains sequence 'Example': " + str_Sample.contains("Example"));
        //String contains method is case sensitive  
        System.out.println("Contains sequence 'example': " + str_Sample.contains("example"));
        System.out.println("Contains sequence 'is String': " + str_Sample.contains("is String"));
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
Contains sequence 'ing': true
Contains sequence 'Example': true
Contains sequence 'example': false
Contains sequence 'is String': false
```